# MEMSQL replication

Tags: database, replication, singlestore

Is there a way we can do replication in mem-sql? I see it is available only on enterprise edition, but I want to do some development before going for enterprise edition. Is there any help on this?

Answer (score 3):

You can download a 30 day trial of MemSQL enterprise edition if you want to try out replication:

http://www.memsql.com/trial/

Comment: Thanks, so it appears to be no way I can use the community edition for replication